# Angular wrapper missing jquery

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection

I am trying to use the [angular-daterangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) wrapper whichdepends on jquery (and moment).
The issue is that the wrapper does not inject jquery, and `$` is not available in window, and I'd rather not to add it. So I get a `$ is not a function` error.

How can I make jquery available into this wrapper ?

Thanks

Comment: You'd either need to load jQuery as the plugin clearly [depends](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker#basic-usage) on jQuery or rewrite the module to not use jQuery and instead use built in jQuery Lite

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks I guess I will have to rewrite it then.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the order of loading dependent libraries:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/momentjs/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-daterangepicker/js/angular-daterangepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css"/>
```

Check out the README.md of [angular-daterangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker).

And also this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9qXWbIQXkgMZYF1kzEv1?p=preview . 
Here you can actually reproduce your issue by just removing jquery lib script tag.

Comment: Thanks. I get the dependencies has to be loaded ... my issue I that the wrapper I try to use is expecting `$` to be available without being injected, so I guess I has to be available in the global scope. I wanted to find a way that would not have me defining jQuery in the global scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "defining jQuery in the global scope"? As soon as you add the library first (before angularjs) it's available everywhere there's no need to explicitly defining it.